# React Native how to fill full space if screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to fill the screen full of buttons. I have function to count the amount of buttons the screen can have. A button is 96px x 96px each button have a margin of 5px Currently the current code works great on iPhones and smaller screen however with iPad it seem as the count is coming in short. I need to be able to set the total amount of block the screen can have

```
import { useWindowDimensions } from "react-native";
const { height, width } = useWindowDimensions();

const handleLayout = (width, height) => {
  let rol = Math.floor(height / (96 + 5));
  let col = Math.floor(width / (96 + 5));

  setTotalBlocks(rol * col);
};

return (
  <View
    onLayout={(event) => {
      const { x, y, width, height } = event.nativeEvent.layout;
      handleLayout(width, height);
    }}
  >
    <FlatGrid
      itemDimension={96}
      scrollEnabled={false}
      data={data}
      fixed
      spacing={10}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
          <PadButton
            item={item}
            navigation={props.navigation}
            btnIsFolder={_handleFolder}
            folderBackBtn={_handleFolderBackBtn}
          />
        </View>
      )}
    />
  </View>
);
```

Comment: Did you tried with PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel instead of Math.floor?

Comment: No. I will give is a shot

Comment: Did it worked ?